# Python ORM Mongo attribute with name containing "__"

Tags: python, django, mongodb

One of developer is trying to query a Mongo document that has name containing `__`.

```
Example Document
{
    "name":"someName"
    "Identifiers":
    {
         "Identifier01": [ "Value1", "Value2"],
         "__identntifier2__" : ["value3", "value4"]
    }
}
```

When he is trying search in python using something like `[ for a new enhancement]`
`filter(Identifiers____identntifier2__)` in python ORM , for obvious reasons , it is throwing errors.

Any idea on how `__` in the name of the attribute can be escaped and not interpreted an operator?

NOTE: We cannot change the attribute name as this is a legacy code and there are quite bit of documents with such named attribute.

Tried `__` , tried `f()` , tried `F()` [ suggestion from chatGpt]

Comment: Can you please share your model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the Model , Identifiers is defined as fields.DynamicField()

Comment: Which ODM are you using?

Comment: PyMongo. Hope this answers.